# Difference between joint_trajectory_action and follow_joint_trajectory

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to find out if there is any difference between `joint_trajectory_action` and `follow_joint_trajectory`.

I used to use `joint_trajectory_action` as the `action_ns` in the `controllers.yaml` file under `(project)_moveit_config/config` folder. Matching this name, when I create the action client in my program I did:

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> ac("joint_trajectory_action",true);
```

This will work for me both for just RViz simulation and driving the real ur3.

Then I changed to use the new `ur_modern_driver`, when I try to bring up the RViz, it will always that it is `waiting for the /joint_trajectory_action to come` up and `Action client not connected: /joint_trajectory_action`. I then tried to use `follow_joint_trajectory` as the `action_ns` in the `controllers.yaml` file. Then when the RViz was brought up it did not complaint and I can launch the

```
(project)_moveit_config/launch/(project)_planning_execution.launch
```

to plan and execute using moveit in simulation. However, when I try to run my program to control the real ur3 then it complaints that it cannot connect to the action server and hence cannot execute trajectory for my program.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328820/difference-between-joint_trajectory_action-and-follow_joint_trajectory/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-18**:
I would suggest to add a bit more context / tell us where you found references to these two names.

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2019-07-18**:
I used to use joint_trajectory_action as the name in the controllers.yaml when using the ur_modern_driver. Eversince I started to use the new driver, it does not seem to work and I have to change it to follow_joint_trajectory in the controllers.yaml but then the RViz simulation doesn't work. So I really want to find out what is wrong or how am I confused.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-18**:
Then please write this in your main question text.

Describe how you used to set things up, then how you set them up now, which contexts this was in, etc.

> Eversince I started to use the new driver

"the new driver": we don't know what you are using, so this reference doesn't tell us much.

> the RViz simulation

and pedantic, but: RViz is not a simulator, only a visualisation tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry for the fuss. I have found the problem. It has nothing to do with any version of the ur_modern_driver. I have found that there was a remap of
follow_joint_trajectory to joint_trajectory_action
in the previous (project)_planning_execution.launch file and that is all it is about.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) with karma: 53 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0